# Cannot retrieve object from OWIN environment with WebAPI2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm working with NHibernate and OWIN. I want to store my SessionFactory within OWIN instead of the old Global.asax.

In my OWIN Startup method I do:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of MobLib.MobDataProvider)(AddressOf MobLib.MobDataProvider.CreateProvider)
```

I've set a breakpoint on when CreateProvider is being called, and I can see that it is successfully called and returns an object as it should.

At a later time, I need to pull this session factory and use it, so I do:

```
Dim context As Microsoft.Owin.IOwinContext = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext
Dim x As MobLib.MobDataProvider = context.Get(Of MobLib.MobDataProvider)("")
```

The only option that seems available to pull from the context requires a key, but one was not required when creating the object per OWIN Context. Also, I've looked through the `Environment` within the OWIN Context and I don't see anything that looks like my data provider.

***I feel like there's something fundamental I'm missing.***

***Update***

I found the object in the Extra dictionary, and the key is quite complex.

[image: Viewing of the Context variable]

Using this, I can get it working for now with this:

```
Dim x As MobLib.MobDataProvider = context.Get(Of MobLib.MobDataProvider)("AspNet.Identity.Owin:MobLib.MobDataProvider, MobLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null")
```

But this seems like a terrible solution. Is there a better way?